# Range changes for functions of stochastic variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the stochastic variables $X=U~(-1,1)$, and $Y=2X^2+1$. I need to find the cdf of $Y$ ($F_Y(y)$). I have reasoned like this:
$$
F_y(y) = P(Y<y) = P(2X^2+1<y) = P(-\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2} < X < \sqrt{\frac{y-1}2})
$$
$$
= \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}}^{\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}}f_X(x)dx = \frac12\left[x\right]_{-\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}}^{\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}} = \frac12\left(\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}+\sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{y-1}2}
$$
Giving us $f_Y(y) = \frac1{2\sqrt2\sqrt{y-1}}$, which is what my book tells me it should be. However, my books tells me this is for the range $1<y<3$, with $0$ and $1$ on either side as is usual for cdfs.

However, I have no idea of how one finds out what this range should be. My book has some examples where the ranges do change, but never explains the reasoning behind these things. Any information on where I can learn this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The question is, if $-1\lt X\lt1$, where is $2X^2+1$? Nothing more to understand, really.

Comment: That line of reasoning brings me to $3<2X^2+1<3$. It seems to work for steadily growing/decreasing linear functions, not for this one.

Comment: Try again: $-1\leqslant x\leqslant1\iff$ $__$ $\leqslant x^2\leqslant$ $__$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X=U(-1,1)$, then $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\in[-1,1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Some care has to be taken when computing

$$\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{y-1}{2}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{y-1}{2}}}f_X(x)dx. $$

We have the following cases

- $\sqrt{\frac{y-1}{2}}\leq 1 \cap y-1\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow  1\leq y\leq 3$

In this case the integral gives the result you wrote as $f_X(x)\neq 0$. The inequality $y-1\geq 0$ is necessary due to the square root $\sqrt{y-1}$ appearing in your computations.

- $\sqrt{\frac{y-1}{2}}\geq 1 \cap y-1\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow  y\leq -1 \cap y\leq 3$

In this second case the integral is identically zero because of the definition of $f_X(x)$ given above.